# How to insert a dynamic view of PLC (As in a IHM Siemens) into Qt (PyQt + Qt Designer)

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, plc, siemens, wincc

I'm designing a GUI which will treat data received from a PLC S7-1200 or S7-1500. I Have the STEP 7 v16 License and designed IHM's view for my system (Basically pumps, tanks of water and sensors). I have done this with Qt Designer and PyQt

[image]

I would like to add on this interface schematic view (interactive or not) of my system :
Something like this which we can find on google by typping WinCC OA

[image]

Or Something Like this which i made on Tia Portal

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'll simply use a GraphicsView which I will dynamically modify depending on the data I will receive from the PLC through an OPC communication.